# Is this valid object propery creation syntax?

Tags: jquery, object

```
editEntry{}
$('#'+rowID+' td[data-field]').each(function() {
    var field = $(this).attr('data-field');
    var value = $(this).text();

    // handle the task complete checkbox
    if(field == 'complete') {
        if($(this).find('input').is(':checked')) {
            editEntry[field]=value;
            editEntry[field][checked]=true; // NOT SURE ABOUT THIS LINE
        }
    }



    editEntry[field]=value;
});
```

Comment: Your `if` is completely useless, since you overwrite the value in the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will only work if `checked` is a variable.

You're probably trying to write

```
editEntry[field].checked=true;
```

However, your code creates a property on a String instance.
**Don't do that**; it's a very bad idea.

Instead, you should probably write something like

```
editEntry[field] = {
    value: value,
    checked: true
};
```